# "Gentleman" is to "male" as what is to "female"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-gender, analogy

For males, it's *gentleman*; and for females?

Comment: Was going to reply *Madame* but then realized that's for *Messer*. By the way, I don't see how "analogy" tag relates to gender.

Comment: As an aside, my 19th century French dictionary has the following definition for gentleman: “title given in England to any well-educated man”, which I thought was kind of nice...

Comment: I would avoid using those kind of sex-specific nouns unless I knew my audience was OK with them.

Comment: That's so simple question. But good to have it here

Answer (score 61):

*Gentlemen* is to *male* as *lady* is to *female*. *Ladies and gentlemen* is used to address the audience during a speech, and *ladies* and *gents* are used on the signs of public toilets for women and men respectively.

Comment: I heard from an old lady a reallady would be the best word

Comment: @rbhattrai: The term [reallady](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reallady) doesn't exist; although you can sound pompous by saying something like: "She's (you're) a real lady". The definition of "real lady" and "perfect gentleman" are subjective.

Comment: @rbhattarai Sometimes "real lady" means "having female organs" in addition to identifying as female. Pretty much anything involving gender is a wide, deep and densely packed minefield of mixed meanings (and extreme sensitivity to vicariously perceived slights). As Sid indicated, saying "that's a *real* lady" is usually intended to be deliberately over-the-top and pretend-pompous.

Answer (score 37):

[Lady](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lady) is the term, although the term [gentlewoman](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gentlewoman) exists.

Comment: @iamsid: Gentlewoman sounds a little archaic to me, like something out of a Jane Austen novel [though I can't quote it here :-)]. Perhaps they used _gentlewoman_ to distinguish it from _lady_, so it didn't sound like the title. I have never heard the word _gentlewoman_ being used in speech.

Comment: I wouldn't say *gentlewoman* is Jane Austin. Much older than that (or perhaps newer, pretending to be older). Medieval fantasy, perhaps.

Comment: Quite an *amiable woman* would be Austen? :)

Comment: In a scene on the television show "The Office", there is a Ben Franklin actor who calls the women of the office 'Gentlewenches' LOL

Comment: @Tragicomic, @TRiG: The term exists in Shakespeare, for example: *When didst thou see me heave up my leg and make 
water against a gentlewoman's farthingale?* (Two Gentlemen of Verona, Act IV Scene 4, and no I didn't just make that up!). In addition a number of other plays have a character known only as "Gentlewoman" :-)

Comment: I would expect "gentlewoman" to mean a high-born woman (as "gentleman" once meant a high-born man).

Comment: Congressional records show that gentlewoman is still used in [this context](http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/R?r112:FLD001:H00847). "Mr. Chairman, I yield 3 min. to the gentlewoman from Connecticut".

Answer (score -4):

My opinion is that the best word this type of woman is the traditional one, which is **[Prude](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=prude&use1828=on)**.

> PRUDE, noun [Gr. [prudence](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=prudence&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on).] A woman of great reserve, coyness, affected stiffness of manners and scrupulous nicety.
>
> Less modest than the speech of prudes.

It's a shame that this word gained became associated with imposing [Bigots](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=bigot&use1828=on) due to of traditional values because I believe the other alternative, [Lady](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=lady&use1828=on) is better reserved as the female counterpart for [Lord](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=Lord&use1828=on). Nobody calls a male without legitimate claim by means of heritage or authority a Lord, so it strikes me as sexist to call females ladies. It is disrespectful to men and perhaps even more importantly, the conflation diminishes the respectability of the title for the women who deserve it.

Although it is odd for somebody to suggest that more patriarchal times would disparage men, it seems evident when comparing the words ladylike and lordlike. Ladylike means the following:

> LA'DY-LIKE, adjective
>
> 1. Like a lady in manners; genteel; well bred.
> 2. Soft; tender; delicate.

Lordlike by means of comparison is

> LORD'LIKE, adjective
>
> 1. Becoming a lord.
> 2. Haughty; proud; insolent.

However I will note that it is *perhaps* the actual difference in behaviors exhibited by Ladies and Lords that accounts for the difference, rather than assumption of inherent behavioral difference between the genders. I can not certainly know, as I have never knowingly met even one aristocratic Lady or aristocratic Lord and have certainly not during the time of an aristocracy, when it was most relevant.

That is not to say we should not be respectable to women but [perverting the definition of Prude](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=Prude&use1913=on) (2) into [what it is considered today](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prude) (3) does not seem to be so especially reverent. Everybody deserves just consideration for their actual merits. [Since it is the latest Public Domain revision, Webster's Revised Unabridged 1913 Dictionary has become fairly widespread,](http://mako.cc/academic/collablit/writing/BenjMakoHill-CollabLit_and_Control/intro.html) so I hope we can see at least some degree of reversion on the matter.

It is worth noting that I would still prefer to consider a prude Ladylike, than [Prudent](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=prudent&use1828=on) despite etymology due to definitions. As far as I know, [Prudence](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=prudence&use1828=on) has always referred to gender neutral virtues. Being Ladylike only requires that a person be like a Lady, as a Prude would be. It seems odd to me that a prude wouldn't refer to any prudent person

Most definitions come from [Noah Webster's American Dictionary of the English Language 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/lordlike)

Prude is further cross-referenced with [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary (1913)](http://thoreau.eserver.org/webster.html) and [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prude) for purposes of analyzing the progressive diminishing of the word.

Dictionary popularity trend speculation based upon [A Collaborative Literary Creation and Control
A Socio-Historic, Technological and Legal Analysis](http://mako.cc/academic/collablit/writing/BenjMakoHill-CollabLit_and_Control/book1.html) Chapter 1 regarding Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary (1913). (Hampshire College)

Comment: "Lady" is a homonym. One definition is the counterpart to gentleman, one definition is the counterpart to lord.

Comment: In this case, I'm paying more attention to the pretenses of the overall entry than a specific definition. Do notice that the royal definition came first and is even still understood, so all of the other definitions are in reference to that.

Comment: While a man might be flattered, or at least not insulted, by being called a *gentleman*, I do not think the same would be true of a woman when given an appellation which denotes -- by the very definition you quote -- *coyness* and *affected stiffness*.  Furthermore, the word is almost certainly going to be misunderstood (from your perspective) in contemporary speech, and likely to give offense, so suggesting it to a non-native speaker (who himself offered "*reallady*"!) is dangerous and bad advice. If you don't like the misapplication of title, then *gentlewoman* is available, per @sid.

Comment: The warning mitigates against the dangers of an insult that is mostly mild. The question was asked in 2011 by an unregistered user, unlikely to revisit, so this is not a direct address too. We may only have one topic to a subject, so knowing this definition, I felt a deep analysis of the word might be interesting to others. On that matter, I think we should parse '*affected stiffness of attitude*' as a whole to mean '*rigid code of conduct*' and coyness to mean chasteness, which aside from being subjective values, are very gentlemanly traits. Also consider the other virtues, like genteelness.